# implement `getcwd(3)` in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a [`getcwd(3)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/getcwd.html) (or [`env::current_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) in Rust std).

In the implementation, I use a `Composer` (an iterator) to yield (call `next()` on `Composer`) each path entry:

- CWD = `/home/steve`, returns `Ok(Some("steve"))`
- CWD = `/home`, returns `Some(Ok("home"))`
- CWD = `/`, returns `None`

###### Src

> [Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=833a5831b605f045a501a62d8c5aa613)

```rust
use std::{
    collections::VecDeque,
    env::set_current_dir,
    ffi::OsString,
    fs::{metadata, read_dir, File},
    io::Result,
    os::{linux::fs::MetadataExt, unix::io::AsRawFd},
    path::PathBuf,
};

use libc::{fchdir, PATH_MAX};

/// A CWD composer, returns the next path entry
///
/// ##### Example
/// * `/home/steve` -> `Some(Ok("steve"))`
/// * `/home` -> `Some(Ok("home"))`
/// * `/` -> `None`
struct Composer;

impl Composer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Composer
    }
}

impl Iterator for Composer {
    type Item = Result<OsString>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let cur_dir_metadata = match metadata(".") {
            Ok(m) => m,
            Err(e) => return Some(Err(e)),
        };
        let parent_metadata = match metadata("..") {
            Ok(m) => m,
            Err(e) => return Some(Err(e)),
        };

        // reaches root
        if cur_dir_metadata.st_dev() == parent_metadata.st_dev()
            && cur_dir_metadata.st_ino() == parent_metadata.st_ino()
        {
            return None;
        }

        // cd to parent dir
        if let Err(e) = set_current_dir("..") {
            return Some(Err(e));
        }

        let dir = match read_dir(".") {
            Ok(dir) => dir,
            Err(e) => return Some(Err(e)),
        };

        for res_entry in dir {
            let entry = match res_entry {
                Ok(entry) => entry,
                Err(e) => return Some(Err(e)),
            };

            let entry_metadata = match entry.metadata() {
                Ok(m) => m,
                Err(e) => return Some(Err(e)),
            };

            if entry_metadata.st_dev() == cur_dir_metadata.st_dev()
                && entry_metadata.st_ino() == cur_dir_metadata.st_ino()
            {
                return Some(Ok(entry.file_name()));
            }
        }
        unreachable!("This is unreachable unless there is something wrong with your file system");
    }
}

pub fn getcwd() -> Result<PathBuf> {
    let cwd = File::open(".")?;

    let comp = Composer::new();
    let mut entries = VecDeque::new();
    for item in comp {
        entries.push_front(item?);
    }

    let mut res = OsString::with_capacity(PATH_MAX as usize);
    entries.iter().for_each(|entry| {
        res.push("/");
        res.push(entry);
    });
    res.shrink_to_fit();

    unsafe { fchdir(cwd.as_raw_fd()) };
    Ok(PathBuf::from(res))
}
```

##### Problem

I am not satisfied with the implementation of `Composer::next()`. Within this method, I have used a lot of functions whose return value is `std::io::Result<T>`, if the return value is an `Err(e)`, I have to match against it and return `Some(Err(e))`. I kind of think this is not idiomatic and Rusty. Can I avoid this or change it to a more natural way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your primary question, my strategy would be something like:

```
impl Composer {
     fn next_component(&self) -> Result<Option<OsStr>> {
        // do your main logic here, since it returns a result, you
        // use ? and simplify the code nicely.
     }
}

impl Iterator for Composer {
     fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item {
        self.next_component().invert()
     }
}
```

Manipulating the current working directory as part of the algorithm is asking for trouble. Instead, you should at least use increasing chains of ".." to ask for parent directories. Honestly, though, getting the current working directory is so low level that its hard to meaningfully reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Yes, since most functions within `Composer::next()` return `io::Result<T>`, [changing the signature to `Result<Option<OsString>>`  plus the use of `?`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c768de17dfbf5b9765dee45e32e766d4) would be neat. Would you like to elaborate on `Instead, you should at least use increasing chains of ".." to ask for parent directories`? Thanks!

Comment: @SteveLau, instead of changing the directory call `metadata("."), metadata(".."), metadata("../.."), metadata("../../..")` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help:)